# Remove google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView from map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

I have a map, which populates markers based on search. I'm attempting to user the newer google maps feature `AdvancedMarkerView` so I can fill it with custom HTML - however, as my search updates, I want to flush the old markers and place new ones when it's called for...and I can't for the life of me figure out how to? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers

The following places the custom markers. It works.

```
const content = document.createElement('div');
content.className = 'marker-title';
content.textContent = item.title;

const marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
  map,
  position: item.position,
  content
});
```

Normally for markers, as in the old markers, I've removed them with the following code, `markers.forEach((marker) => marker.setMap(null))` however this doesn't seem to work for the advanced markers. Since the marker returned when creating the advanced marker points to the element, I also tried doing a `marker.remove()` thinking the HTML element would be targeted, but no cigar.

I haven't been able to find any concrete examples on the Google API docs, when it comes to advanced markers, and same for others asking the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `setMap()` or other method to call on the [<s>`AdvancedMarkerView`</s> AdvancedMarkerElement class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers) to toggle its visibility or remove it from the map.

Although it is not super clear, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/add-marker) says:

> To remove a marker from the map, set the `markerView.map` property to `null`.

Working example below:

```js
async function initMap() {

  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 37.39094933041195, lng: -122.02503913145092 },
    zoom: 14,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  const draggableMarker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: { lat: 37.39094933041195, lng: -122.02503913145092 },
    gmpDraggable: true,
    title: "This marker is draggable. Click to remove.",
  });
  
  draggableMarker.addListener("click", (event) => {
  
    // Remove AdvancedMarkerElement from Map
    draggableMarker.map = null;
  });
  
  map.addListener("click", (event) => {
  
    // Set AdvancedMarkerView position and add to Map
    draggableMarker.position = event.latLng;
    draggableMarker.map = map;
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk",
    v: "weekly",
  });
</script>
```