# Remove AdvancedMarkerView Google Mapsv3 Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, vuejs3, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

Want to clear `AdvancedMarkerView` in Google Maps API v3 and using Vue3. Getting a difficult to parse error when using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74492809/903143):

`Uncaught TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property '__e3_' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '#<Object>' but got '#<Object>')`

My markers are stored in a pinia store. Here is how I'm trying to remove them:

```js
  MapItemStore.mapMarkers.forEach((marker, index) =>
    // console.log(marker.map)
    // loggin the `marker.map` works and returns values. SEE SCREENSHOT BELOW

    marker.map = null  // returns the error message above
  )
  MapItemStore.mapMarkers = []
  .. other stuff
```

`marker.map` seems to exist so I'm not sure why setting it to null as recommended doesn't work. Here's what is returned when logging `marker.map`:

[image: Console Log of the marker.map output]

How can I remove these AdvancedMarkerView's in Vue3?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code required to answer your question, see [ask]

Comment: @geocodezip where do you see pictures of code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Vue 3 uses proxies on all of it's objects. To fix this you need to use the `toRaw()` function to get the raw object from the proxy. Then manipulate it.

```js
import { toRaw } from "vue";
...

MapItemStore.mapMarkers.forEach((marker, index) =>
    toRaw(marker).map = null;
);
```